# app.xaml "cannot be edited in design view"

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am building a wpf form in c#. two hours ago I opened my project and the design view was closed. I've tried right clicking the form and pressing "open with...", but no option appears to open it in design view.

Comment: `App.xaml` usually isn't intended to be edited in design view. It's the startup page that will load other UI windows (probably something like `MainWindow.xaml`) that you can open in design view.

Comment: Now what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `App.xaml` then isn't probably the file you wanted to edit.
If you wanted to change something in a designer, check for your `MainWindow.xaml`. This is by default the first `Window` which shows up, after starting your application.

For your information: The default `Window` which opens up at startup can be set in `App.xaml` with the `MainWindow` property.